# Solve for $x$: $\frac{x^2-10x+15}{x^2-6x+15}=\frac{3x}{x^2-8x+15}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Solve the equation: $\dfrac{x^2-10x+15}{x^2-6x+15}=\dfrac{3x}{x^2-8x+15}$.

When $x\ne3$ and $x\ne5$ we get $$(x^2-10x+15)(x^2-8x+15)=3x(x^2-6x+15)\\(x^2-9x+15-x)(x^2-9x+15+x)-3x(x^2-6x+15)=0\\(x^2-9x+15)^2-x^2-3x(x^2-6x+15)=0.$$ I am stuck here. The Rational Root Theorem won't be useful as the equation does not have such roots.

I got $-9x$ by averaging $-10x$ and $-8x$.

I don't know if it makes sense.

Comment: Quadratic formula:  $$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(7-i \sqrt{11}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(7+i
   \sqrt{11}\right),7-\sqrt{34},7+\sqrt{34}\right\}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y:=x^2-6x+15$ so$$\frac{y-4x}{y}=\frac{3x}{y-2x}\implies y^2-6xy+8x^2=3xy\implies (y-x)(y-8x)=0.$$That gives you two quadratics to solve.

Comment: May I ask you how do we factor $y^2-9xy+8x^2$?

Comment: @mat1 It's a homogeneous polynomial, $x^2(z^2-9z+8)$ with $z:=y/x$, so if you know how to factorize a quadratic in one variable you can factorize a homogeneous quadratic in two variables.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: divide the numerators and denominators by $x \ne 0$ and let $z = x + \dfrac{15}{x}\,$, then:

$$
\frac{z-10}{z-6} = \frac{3}{z-8}
$$

Comment: I would do the same

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying to a common denominator and factoring we obtain
$$
0=x^4 - 21x^3 + 128x^2 - 315x + 225=(x^2 - 7x + 15)(x^2 - 14x + 15).
$$

Comment: Care to show how did you factor? I believe there's a different more styly solution.

Comment: I multiplied $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and compared coefficients with $x^4-\cdots +225$. The quartic polynomial has no rational root by the Rational Root Theorem- as you say. So we need quadratic factors. Of course there often is - afterwards- a more "styly" solution. The question is whether we learn more by a "styly" solution or by trying ourselves.

Comment: I completely agree with you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking from where you left off, and rewrite the left hand side of your last line:
$\begin{align}(x^2+15)^2 - 18x(x^2+15)  + 81x^2 - x^2 -3x(x^2+15)+18x^2&=0\\ \implies (x^2+15)^2-21x(x^2+15)+98x^2&=0\\ \implies (x^2+15)^2 - 2\cdot 10x\cdot (x^2+15)+(10x)^2 - x(x^2+15)-2x^2&=0\\ \implies (x^2+15-10x)^2-x(x^2+15-10x)-12x^2&=0\\ \implies (x^2-10x+15 -4x)(x^2-10x+15 + 3x) &= 0 \\ \implies (x^2-14x+15)(x^2-7x+15)&=0 \end{align}$

From this you can use quadratic formula to calculate the roots.